# How to output the largest number from objects in array for high scores in quiz game in javascript?

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface

I'm making a javascript CLI quiz app and I want to compare the highest score from the database/data structure and the user's score. But I can't figure out a way to output the largest score from the objects in the array. Right now the code I've provided below only compares to the last indexed score from the array.

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
var userName = readlineSync.question("Hey there! Can you tell us your Name? " )
console.log("Welcome! " + userName + " let's play a game 'Do you know Manan?'")
var score = 0;

 var highscore = [{
   name: "Jay",
   score: 5,
 }, {
   name: "Sanan",
   score: 2,
 } ]

function qna(question, answer){
  var userAnswer = readlineSync.question(question);

  if (userAnswer.toUpperCase() === answer.toUpperCase()){
    console.log("You're Right!");
    score = score + 1;
  } else {
    console.log("You're Wrong!");
  }

  console.log("Your score: " + score);
}

questionOne = {
  question: "Who is my favorite superhero? ",
  answer: "thor",
}

questionTwo = {
  question: "Which is my favorite Movie? ",
  answer: "la la land",
}

questionThree = {
  question: "Which is my favorite food? ",
  answer: "pasta",
}


var quiz = [questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree]

for (i=0; i < quiz.length; i++){
  var currentq = quiz[i];
  qna(currentq.question, currentq.answer);
}

 for (i=0; i < highscore.length; i++){
   var currenthq = highscore[i];
 }





 if (score > currenthq.score){
   console.log("Woohoo! You've beaten the high score. Send me a screenshot and I'll update it. ");
 } else {
   console.log("Thank You for playing! ");
 }
```

Comment: So if the current player scores higher than anyone in the array, you want to add their name and highscore to the array?

Answer (score 0):

When you run:

```js
for (i=0; i < highscore.length; i++){
  currenthq = highscore[i];
}
```

what you are doing is looping through `highscore` and setting `currenthq` to be the current one, without any condition. So by the time the loop is over, **`currenthq` will always be the last element in `highscore` array**. What you want to do is check if `highscore[i]` has a higher score than `currenthq` and update it **only if** that is the case. So:

```js
//a dummy highscore
let currenthq = {
  name: "...",
  score: 0
}

for (let i = 0; i < highscore.length; i++) {
  if(highscore[i].score > currenthq.score){
    // change currenthq only if highscore[i] has a higher score.
    currenthq = highscore[i]
  }
}
```

Your code currently has possible issues with hoisting, and you should avoid using `var` keyword. You can instead use `let` or `const` to declare mutable and immutable variables respectively.

Answer (score 0):

> The code I've provided below only compares to the last indexed score from the array.

```
for (i = 0; i < highscore.length; i++) {
  var currenthq = highscore[i];
}
```

This loop is the reason it is only compared with the last element. Instead of simply assigning the `currenthq` to `highscore[i]`. You need to check first if the `currenthq` is greater than before.

However, there's a simple way to achieve the same result by using the [sort method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
const currenthq = highscore.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score)[0];
```